# Mysql using DISTINCT on 2 fields only

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a mysql database table as follows

> id | uid | touid | message | time

This database has the messages sent from one person to another person. I need to fetch the latest messages transferred between me and all other users.

Currently I am using a query as follows:

```
SELECT uid, touid, message, time
FROM messages
WHERE uid = "'.$currentuser.'"
    OR touid = "'.$currentuser.'"
ORDER by time DESC;
```

Which will get all the message between me and any other user. But I need to show only the set latest messages transferred between me and all other users.

It tried using GROUP BY but the ordering gets affected. So is there any other solution?

Any ideas? If I am not clear please comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  m1.*
FROM 
  messages m1
 JOIN 
  (SELECT UID, TOUID, MAX(time) time FROM messages GROUP BY UID, TOUID) m2
 ON m1.UID=m2.UID AND m1.TOUID=m2.TOUID and m1.time=m2.time
WHERE 
  m1.uid = "'.$currentuser.'"
ORDER BY
  m1.time DESC;
```

Comment: But it will give only messages **from** currentuser

Comment: @ypercube: Because of the WHERE clause. Remove it and will bring for all the users.

Answer (score 0):

Add `LIMIT 1` in the end of your query.

Comment: No no, I want the latest message transferred to all other users too. (Not only between 2 users)

Answer (score 0):

try to use to cut unwanted rows

```
limit 1
```

Comment: No no, I want the latest message transferred to all other users too. (Not only between 2 users)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT uid,touid,message,time
FROM messages AS m
JOIN (
    SELECT uid,touid,MAX(time) AS time
    FROM messages
    WHERE uid = "'.$currentuser.'"
        OR touid = "'.$currentuser.'"
) AS x ON (m.uid=x.uid,m.touid=x.touid,m.time=x.time)
ORDER BY time DESC;
```